# Open href in link only after certain events have executed

Tags: javascript, jquery, href, preventdefault

I have a link to the Tumblr share widget, and need to append some query string params to it before it opens (triggered by clicking on the link). However, the link opens before these params are appended, I think because it takes a few seconds-- I'm sending an image on the page to be hosted on imgur and returning that URL.

Is there any way to delay the new link from being opened until AFTER my new image url is returned??? I've tried using `e.preventDefault();` and `return false;` but haven't had any luck.

My HTML is:

```
<button id='tumblrshare'>tumblr</button


$('body').on('click','#tumblrshare',function(e){
var svg = $("#svg")[0];
svg.toDataURL("image/png", {
    callback: function(img) {
    var img = img.replace("data:image/png;base64,", "");
    var imgurTitle = $("meta[property='og:title']").attr("content");
    $.ajax({ 
          url: 'https://api.imgur.com/3/image',
          headers: {'Authorization': 'Client-ID **********'},
          type: 'POST',
          data: {'image': img, 'type': 'base64', 'title': imgurTitle},
          success: function(result) { 
          imageURL = result.data.link;
          window.location = 'https://www.tumblr.com/widgets/share/tool?canonicalUrl=http://www.example.com&caption=mycaption&posttype=photo&content=' + imageURL;
          },
          error: function(){
            console.log('error');
          }
    }); //ajax
  }//callback

});//svg

}); //tumblrshare
```

Please help!!

Comment: Why not use `$('#tumblrshare')...` to begin with? When is this JS executed?

Comment: I could, it's the same thing. This is just a js file that's loaded at the bottom of the page.

Comment: <button id='tumblrshare'>tumblr</button
</button is not closed

Comment: Typo on my part...in my file it's closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Altering the 'href' attribute of a link won't change it's destination once it's already been clicked.  Consider using `window.location` to redirect the user when your ajax call is complete.

```
$('body').on('click','#tumblrshare',function(e){
   e.preventDefault(); // Stop the default behaviour
   ...
   $.ajax({
    success: function(result){
      window.location = result.data.link;
    },
    ...
  });
...
});
```

Comment: So, the place the link needs to go to is actually the <a id='tumblrshare' link in my html). Can I just say window.location = $('#tumblrshare).attr('href')?

Comment: Yes, though in jquery you'd want to write `$('#tumblrshare').attr('href')` to get that value

Comment: Yeah, I changed it to  $('#tumblrshare').attr('href') and the link is still jumping. I also tried using e.stopPropogation, to no avail..

Comment: Do you have any errors in your console?  [Here's a simple fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9521do0f/) to show `e.preventDefault()` working in this scenario

Comment: No errors--I've used e.preventDefault() before, pretty well, so I'm not sure why this isn't working!!

Comment: window.location ended up working, although I needed to put this as a callback to my ajax, not in success:

Answer (score 1):

```
function loadTumblr(){
    var svg = $("#svg")[0];
    svg.toDataURL("image/png", {
        callback: function(img) {
            var img = img.replace("data:image/png;base64,", "");
            var imgurTitle = $("meta[property='og:title']").attr("content");
            $.ajax({ 
                url: 'https://api.imgur.com/3/image',
                headers: {'Authorization': 'Client-ID **********'},
                type: 'POST',
                data: {'image': img, 'type': 'base64', 'title': imgurTitle},
                success: function(result) { 
                    imageURL = result.data.link;
                    window.location.href = 'https://www.tumblr.com/widgets/share/tool?canonicalUrl=http://www.example.com&caption=mycaption&posttype=photo&content=' + imageURL;
                },
                error: function(){
                    console.log('error');
                }
            }); //ajax
        }//callback
    });//svg
}
```

Comment: Maybe just change it from an anchor to a div and fire an onClick event that runs your AJAX call. Inside of the success function, add a window.location = result.data.link;

Comment: Yeah I changed it to a button instead, and I think that's helping...now the only issue is that the window.location doesn't change...let me update my code above.

Comment: Got it working! Changing the a href to a button helped a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```js
   $("a.alate").on("click",function(event){
 _thislink = $(this).attr("href");
event.preventDefault();
 console.log(_thislink);
$.ajax({
    type: 'get',
    url : 'https://restcountries.eu/rest/v1/all',
   fail:function(data) {
   console.log("fail");
  }
 }).done(function(data) {
  //  when request finish 
   console.log(data);
   //   window.location = _thislink;
 });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a class="alate" href="http://stackoverflow.com">Update Data then go</a>
```

the most important on you code to use

```
e.preventDefault();
```

to stop default behavior of href

Comment: Yeah, I've been using e.preventDefault(); (changed code above), but it's still making the jump.

Comment: in this code its jump after finish request
// window.location = _thislink;
comment this line it will not

Comment: try this code now ! run snippet and see it will bring data without go the link uncomment going to link then it will go link only after bring data

Comment: then you have problem some where else not on this link 
see unclosed a error with Javascripts